Who writes all the unnumbered summary text, on top a Supreme Court of Canada Justice's judgement?
Peruse Ledcor Construction Ltd. v. Northbridge Indemnity Insurance Co. 2016 SCC 37 as example. I am referring to the numberless text commencing with

During construction, a building’s windows were scratched by the cleaners hired to clean them. The cleaners used improper tools and methods in carrying out their work, and as a result, the windows had to be replaced. The building’s owner and the general contractor in charge of the construction project claimed the cost of replacing the windows against a builders’ risk insurance policy issued in their favour and covering all contractors involved in the construction. The insurers denied coverage on the basis of an exclusion contained in the policy for the “cost of making good faulty workmanship”.

and ending

The question the present case raises involves applying a legal standard to a set of facts and does not give rise to any extricable question of law. The legal principle is that “making good faulty workmanship” means “the cost of redoing the faulty work”. This principle does not operate at a very high level of generality. Applying that principle turns on the scope of the faulty work and the nature of redoing it, and its application in other cases will ultimately be decided on a case‑by‑case basis in light of the particular circumstances of the particular case.

Up to here, who wrote all this?
Unquestionably, I am not asking for the numbered paragraphs beginning with

The judgment of McLachlin C.J. and Abella, Moldaver, Karakatsanis, Wagner, Gascon, Côté and Brown JJ. was delivered by
WAGNER J. —
I.              Introduction
[1]                              The outcome of these appeals hinges on the interpretation of an exclusion clause in a common form of all-risk property insurance, variably referred to as “builders’ risk”, “contractors’ risk”, “all risks”, “multi-risk” or “course of construction” insurance.


Some member of the court staff writes it, presumably.  Are you looking for their job title, their name, ...?

In the US Supreme Court, the summary text that precedes the court's opinion is called the syllabus and is prepared by an official called the Reporter of Decisions (presumably they could also delegate the task to a subordinate). The current Reporter of Decisions is Rebecca Anne Womeldorf.
